Windows 10 - I messed up permission to write and modify in system Security tab
EDIT. I can see there are votes to close my Question and I understand the reasons. I will give the Question a go for some (short) time and then delete it. I was hoping for some default actions to restore settings the default state. I don't understand what has happened and can't explain what I did. I will be honest: this is frustrating!

OS: Windows 10 64bit Home Edition.
Hello,
I am afraid I have done something I can't explain and probably messed up settings in Security tab of the File Explorer. Some applications, not all, report problems with not begin able to write into folders. Sometimes this window pups up:

Other applications simply report errors not making an auto backup due to not having permissions. Funny enough, if I try to save a file manually, applications create an empty file, and then I can overwrite on such file.
I did try to read and understand how Windows 10 handles permission rights. I did a few steps and thought I managed to sort it out, but it seems I still have no rights to save into folders.
I listed steps I have done tried. Essentially, I tried to add my account to a list of existing entries in the Security tab for a specific folder. Then, I explicitly set the same folder in programs that make auto backups or where I try to save files.
For some reason the problem still remains.
It would be great to restore settings to default but I would really like to understand why this is happening.
Thanks

Here are the steps I have done so far
In the Security tab, I clicked Advanced, followed by Add, and then I clicked on Select a Principal:

In next pop up window I clicked on Advanced and Find Now where I have found my user account:

Then, I checked if my account was within the list of existing entries. It is still there with permissions to Modify or Write. I also selected so that subfolders and files would inherit the settings. Here's how my Security tab looks like:

and here are permissions for my account:


did you mess up just one or two directories, or did you do something to the whole disk or a major portion of it? and why does your error message say "network location"?

I don't know why it says network location. It's a local disk. I do not share anything, nor am I a member of any home group. As to what exactly I messed up, it is probably disk because this issues happens in two different folders on the same disk. There is no issue to save in Desktop.

Are you the sole administrator?

Quickest attempt to fix such non-specific issue (which folders are involved?) is to try reinstalling Win 10 from ISO, keeping files.

@security_paranoid I have only one account, me, and I am Administrator

This is related to one of the disks D:. while C: is OK. I honestly haven't done much. Just clicked one or two things and accepted it. I can't even remember what it was. From the images, we can see, all default entries are still there. To my best knowledge I haven't really touched them. I can't believe such a small mistake can ruin everything to the point I have to reinstall the entire system.

Perhaps it has something to do with my anti-virus? I used Comodo Internet Security.

So what did you do or what were you trying to do? Understanding what you were trying to accomplish might help us explain how you reverse what you did without an in-place upgrade (also known as reinstalling Windows). If you suspect the AV software. Uninstall it.

When you look at the errors you receive, what drive or storage location do they all have in common? Changing permissions isn't "not doing much", it is doing a LOT, as you've seen. Don't excuse yourself or downplay. We've all done dumb things on our paths learning tech. Say clearly and directly what you have done, to the best of your knowledge, and that will give us the best chance of helping you.

You change the owner on a large collection of files and folders. In order to tell if we even CAN help, we'll need to know HOW LARGE a collection that was. Was it an entire drive, or just an important folder or two? What problem were you trying to solve when you made that change? You note you changed a couple folders, but WHAT folders? We need that information.

@DrMoishePippik Perhaps this is the quickest fix but what if it happens again after re-install? I would really like to understand what is causing the issue. Anyway, I understand nobody can help me unless I could reproduce/explain the problem. Since I can't because I didn't do obvious actions to me, I will probably have to "live with it". Thanks

"I will give the Question a go for some (short) time and then delete it." - Receiving close votes is a reason to [edit] the question not delete it, but sadly, adding meta commentary saying you plan to delete the question isn't allowed either. Say I did have an answer, or i planned on spending time to research your problem, knowing you will delete the question will prevent me from doing either. Consider addressing the reason you are getting close votes instead of deleting the question. I don't believe this is a case of "can't provide info" I think it's a case of "have not provided info"
